# Customize Multi-Column Tag Map to fetch specific post-type

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, tags

I'm using a plugin called "[Multi-Column Tag Map](http://tugbucket.net/wordpress/wordpress-plugin-multi-column-tag-map/)" that lets you display all tags that were used and arrange them in a alphabetical order. This plugin works fine in a regular post-type but It's not working on a custom post-type that I created. I created a new post-type called 'books' and has an additional taxonomy(Tags) of 'Writers' and 'Tags'.

I followed this to create my custom post type:
http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/04/29/custom-post-types-in-wordpress

How do i customize this to fetch my tags from my custom post-type?

This is the plugin code:

-- code removed, updated version below.

**Update:**

The purpose of this plugin on my site is to list all tags that we're used for the books. So user can just go to that page and browse articles/books by tags that were used.

I also tried Helgatheviking solution, It's similar to the plugin (Multi-Column Tag Map). But  I'll just be sticking on customizing the plugin for the meantime as the plugin already provide some formatting. I just need to deal with get_terms().

My current problem is when using Helgatheviking or the Multi-Column Tag Map plugin solution, they're both using get_terms(). and get_terms() only fetch tags that in my posts and not in my custom post-type ('books'). I wanted to fetch tags from my custom post type.

So I did a little search and found [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14331/get-terms-by-taxonomy-and-post-type) get_terms_by_post_type() by Bainternet. I think this is the solution in fetching tags to a certain post-type get_terms().

So this is what I did (code below), Unfortunately I have an error in my foreach(). It said
"Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in mctagmap.php on line 366"

**Additional Details:**

post-type i'm targeting = 'the_books'

taxonomy i'm targeting = 'book_tags', 'book_writers' -- This might sound dumb, but I use 'post_tag' below instead of any of those two because I want to target the two of them.

**mctagmap.php** (modified version)

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Multi-column Tag Map 
Plugin URI: http://tugbucket.net/wordpress/wordpress-plugin-multi-column-tag-map/
Description: Multi-column Tag Map displays a columnized  and alphabetical (English) listing of all tags used in your site similar to the index pages of a book.
Version: 8.0
Author: Alan Jackson
Author URI: http://tugbucket.net
*/

/*  Copyright 2009-2011  Alan Jackson (alan[at]tugbucket.net)

    This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
    (at your option) any later version.

    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
    Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
*/


/* get terms limited to post type 
 @ $taxonomies - (string|array) (required) The taxonomies to retrieve terms from. 
 @ $args  -  (string|array) all Possible Arguments of get_terms http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms
 @ $post_type - (string|array) of post types to limit the terms to
 @ $fields - (string) What to return (default all) accepts ID,name,all,get_terms. 
 if you want to use get_terms arguments then $fields must be set to 'get_terms'
*/

function get_terms_by_post_type($taxonomies,$args,$post_type,$fields = 'all'){
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => (array)$post_type,
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $terms = array();
    while ($the_query->have_posts()){
        $the_query->the_post();
        $curent_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy);
        foreach ($curent_terms as $t){
          //avoid duplicates
            if (!in_array($t,$terms)){
                $terms[] = $c;
            }
        }
    }
    wp_reset_query();
    //return array of term objects
    if ($fields == "all")
        return $terms;
    //return array of term ID's
    if ($fields == "ID"){
        foreach ($terms as $t){
            $re[] = $t->term_id;
        }
        return $re;
    }
    //return array of term names
    if ($fields == "name"){
        foreach ($terms as $t){
            $re[] = $t->name;
        }
        return $re;
    }
    // get terms with get_terms arguments
    if ($fields == "get_terms"){
        $terms2 = get_terms( $taxonomies, $args );
        foreach ($terms as $t){
            if (in_array($t,$terms2)){
                $re[] = $t;
            }
        }
        return $re;
    }
}


function wp_mcTagMap($options='') {

    $ns_options = array(
                    "columns" => "2",
                    "more" => "View More",
                    "hide" => "no",
                    "num_show" => "5",
                    "toggle" => "no",
                    "show_empty" => "yes",
                   );

    if(strpos($options, '|')) {        
    $options = explode("|",$options);
    } else {
    $options = explode("&",$options);
    }

    foreach ($options as $option) {

        $parts = explode("=",$option);
        $options[$parts[0]] = $parts[1];

    }

    if ($options['columns']) {
    $ns_options['columns'] = $options['columns'];
    } else {
    $options['columns'] = 2;
    }

    if ($options['more']) {
    $ns_options['more'] = htmlentities($options['more'], ENT_QUOTES);
    } else {
    $options['more'] = "View more";
    }

    if ($options['hide']) {
    $ns_options['hide'] = $options['hide'];
    } else {
    $options['hide'] = "no";
    }

    if ($options['num_show']) {
    $ns_options['num_show'] = $options['num_show'];
    } else {
    $options['num_show'] = 5;
    }

    if ($options['toggle']) {
    $ns_options['toggle'] = $options['toggle'];
    } else {
    $options['toggle'] = "no";
    }

    if ($options['show_empty']) {
    $ns_options['show_empty'] = $options['show_empty'];
    } else {
    $options['show_empty'] = "yes";
    }

    $show_empty = $options['show_empty'];
    if($show_empty == "yes"){
        $show_empty = "0";
    }
    if($show_empty == "no"){
        $show_empty = "1";
    }
    $list = '<!-- begin list --><div id="mcTagMap">';
    $gtargs = array('orderby' => 'count', 'order' => 'ASC',  'hide_empty' => $show_empty);
    $terms = get_terms_by_post_type('post_tag',$gtargs,'the_books','get_terms');
    $groups = array();



    if( $tags && is_array( $tags ) ) {
        foreach( $tags as $tag ) {
            $first_letter = strtoupper( $tag->name[0] );
            $groups[ $first_letter ][] = $tag;
        }
    if( !empty ( $groups ) ) {  
        $count = 0;
        $howmany = count($groups);

        // this makes 2 columns
        if ($options['columns'] == 2){
        $firstrow = ceil($howmany * 0.5);
        $secondrow = ceil($howmany * 1);
        $firstrown1 = ceil(($howmany * 0.5)-1);
        $secondrown1 = ceil(($howmany * 1)-0);
        }


        //this makes 3 columns
        if ($options['columns'] == 3){
        $firstrow = ceil($howmany * 0.33);
        $secondrow = ceil($howmany * 0.66);
        $firstrown1 = ceil(($howmany * 0.33)-1);
        $secondrown1 = ceil(($howmany * 0.66)-1);
        }

        //this makes 4 columns
        if ($options['columns'] == 4){
        $firstrow = ceil($howmany * 0.25);
        $secondrow = ceil(($howmany * 0.5)+1);
        $firstrown1 = ceil(($howmany * 0.25)-1);
        $secondrown1 = ceil(($howmany * 0.5)-0);
        $thirdrow = ceil(($howmany * 0.75)-0);
        $thirdrow1 = ceil(($howmany * 0.75)-1);
        }

        //this makes 5 columns
        if ($options['columns'] == 5){
        $firstrow = ceil($howmany * 0.2);
        $firstrown1 = ceil(($howmany * 0.2)-1);
        $secondrow = ceil(($howmany * 0.4));
        $secondrown1 = ceil(($howmany * 0.4)-1);
        $thirdrow = ceil(($howmany * 0.6)-0);
        $thirdrow1 = ceil(($howmany * 0.6)-1);
        $fourthrow = ceil(($howmany * 0.8)-0);
        $fourthrow1 = ceil(($howmany * 0.8)-1);
        }

        foreach( $groups as $letter => $tags ) { 
            if ($options['columns'] == 2){
            if ($count == 0 || $count == $firstrow || $count ==  $secondrow) { 
                if ($count == $firstrow){
                $list .= "\n<div class='holdleft noMargin'>\n";
                $list .="\n";
                } else {
                $list .= "\n<div class='holdleft'>\n";
                $list .="\n";
                }
                }
                }
            if ($options['columns'] == 3){
            if ($count == 0 || $count == $firstrow || $count ==  $secondrow) { 
                if ($count == $secondrow){
                $list .= "\n<div class='holdleft noMargin'>\n";
                $list .="\n";
                } else {
                $list .= "\n<div class='holdleft'>\n";
                $list .="\n";
                }
                }
                }
            if ($options['columns'] == 4){              
            if ($count == 0 || $count == $firstrow || $count ==  $secondrow || $count == $thirdrow) { 
                if ($count == $thirdrow){
                $list .= "\n<div class='holdleft noMargin'>\n";
                $list .="\n";
                } else {
                $list .= "\n<div class='holdleft'>\n";
                $list .="\n";
                }
                }
                }
            if ($options['columns'] == 5){
            if ($count == 0 || $count == $firstrow || $count ==  $secondrow || $count == $thirdrow || $count == $fourthrow ) { 
                if ($count == $fourthrow){
                $list .= "\n<div class='holdleft noMargin'>\n";
                $list .="\n";
                } else {
                $list .= "\n<div class='holdleft'>\n";
                $list .="\n";
                }
                }
                }

    $list .= '<div class="tagindex">';
    $list .="\n";
    $list .='<h4>' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $letter ) . '</h4>';
    $list .="\n";
    $list .= '<ul class="links">';
    $list .="\n";           
    $i = 0;
    foreach( $tags as $tag ) {
        $url = attribute_escape( get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ) );
        $name = apply_filters( 'the_title', $tag->name );
    //  $name = ucfirst($name);
        $i++;
        $counti = $i;
        if ($options['hide'] == "yes"){
        $num2show = $options['num_show'];
        $num2show1 = ($options['num_show'] +1);
        $toggle = ($options['toggle']);

        if ($i != 0 and $i <= $num2show) {
            $list .= '<li><a title="' . $name . '" href="' . $url . '">' . $name . '</a></li>';
            $list .="\n";
            }
        if ($i > $num2show && $i == $num2show1 && $toggle == "no") {
            $list .=  "<li class=\"morelink\">"."<a href=\"#x\" class=\"more\">".$options['more']."</a>"."</li>"."\n";
            }
        if ($i >= $num2show1){
               $list .= '<li class="hideli"><a title="' . $name . '" href="' . $url . '">' . $name . '</a></li>';
               $list .="\n";
        }
        } else {
            $list .= '<li><a title="' . $name . '" href="' . $url . '">' . $name . '</a></li>';
            $list .="\n";
        }   

    } 
        if ($options['hide'] == "yes" && $toggle != "no" && $i == $counti && $i > $num2show) {
            $list .=  "<li class=\"morelink\">"."<a href=\"#x\" class=\"more\">".$options['more']."</a>"."<a href=\"#x\" class=\"less\">".$options['toggle']."</a>"."</li>"."\n";
        }    
    $list .= '</ul>';
    $list .="\n";
    $list .= '</div>';
    $list .="\n\n";
        if ($options['columns'] == 3 || $options['columns'] == 2){
        if ( $count == $firstrown1 || $count == $secondrown1) { 
            $list .= "</div>"; 
            }   
            }
        if ($options['columns'] == 4){
        if ( $count == $firstrown1 || $count == $secondrown1 || $count == $thirdrow1) { 
            $list .= "</div>"; 
            }   
            }
        if ($options['columns'] == 5){      
        if ( $count == $firstrown1 || $count == $secondrown1 || $count == $thirdrow1 || $count == $fourthrow1) { 
            $list .= "</div>"; 
            }   
            }

        $count++;
            } 
        } 
    $list .="</div>";
    $list .= "<div style='clear: both;'></div></div><!-- end list -->";
        }
    else $list .= '<p>Sorry, but no tags were found</p>';

print $list ;

}
// end long code

// short code begins
function sc_mcTagMap($atts, $content = null) {
        extract(shortcode_atts(array(
                    "columns" => "2",
                    "more" => "View More",
                    "hide" => "no",
                    "num_show" => "5",
                    "toggle" => "no",
                    "show_empty" => "yes",
                    "name_divider" => "|", // added 09.02.11
                    "tag_count" => "no",
                    "exclude" => "",
                    "descriptions" => "no",
                    "width" => "",
                    "equal" => "no",
        ), $atts));

    if($show_empty == "yes"){
        $show_empty = "0";
    }
    if($show_empty == "no"){
        $show_empty = "1";
    }

    if($width){
        $tug_width = "style=\"width: ". $width ."px;\"";
    }
    if($equal == "yes" && $columns != "1"){ 
        $equalize = 'mcEqualize';
    }
    if($toggle != "no"){
        $toggable = "toggleYes";
    } else {
        $toggable = "toggleNo";
    }
    $list = '<!-- begin list --><div id="mcTagMap" class="'.$equalize.' '.$toggable.'">';
    //$tags = get_terms('post_tag', 'order=ASC&hide_empty='.$show_empty.''); // new code!
    $gtargs = array('orderby' => 'count', 'order' => 'ASC',  'hide_empty' => $show_empty);
    $terms = get_terms_by_post_type('post_tag',$gtargs,'the_books','get_terms');

    /* exclude tags */  
    foreach($tags as $tag){
        $fl = mb_substr($tag->name,0,1);
        $ll = mb_substr($tag->name,1);
        $tag->name = $fl.$ll;
        if (preg_match('/(?<=^|[^\p{L}])' . preg_quote($tag->name,'/') . '(?=[^\p{L}]|$)/ui', $exclude)) {
            unset($tag->name);
        }
    }

    $groups = array();
    if( $tags && is_array( $tags ) ) {
        foreach( $tags as $tag ) {  
        /* exclude tags */
        if(isset($tag->name)){  
            // added 09.02.11
            if (strlen(strstr($tag->name, $name_divider))>0) {
                $tag->name = preg_replace("/\s*([\\".$name_divider."])\s*/", "$1", $tag->name);
                $tagParts = explode($name_divider, $tag->name);
                $tag->name = $tagParts[1].', '.$tagParts[0];
            }

            $first_letter = mb_strtoupper( mb_substr($tag->name,0,1) ); /* Thanks to Birgir Erlendsson */
            $groups[ $first_letter ][] = $tag;
            ksort($groups);
        }
        }
    if( !empty ( $groups ) ) {  
        $count = 0;
        $howmany = count($groups);

        // this makes 2 columns
        if ($columns == 2){
        $firstrow = ceil($howmany * 0.5);
        $secondrow = ceil($howmany * 1);
        $firstrown1 = ceil(($howmany * 0.5)-1);
        $secondrown1 = ceil(($howmany * 1)-0);
        }


        //this makes 3 columns
        if ($columns == 3){
        $firstrow = ceil($howmany * 0.33);
        $secondrow = ceil($howmany * 0.66);
        $firstrown1 = ceil(($howmany * 0.33)-1);
        $secondrown1 = ceil(($howmany * 0.66)-1);
        }

        //this makes 4 columns
        if ($columns == 4){
        $firstrow = ceil($howmany * 0.25);
        $secondrow = ceil(($howmany * 0.5)+1);
        $firstrown1 = ceil(($howmany * 0.25)-1);
        $secondrown1 = ceil(($howmany * 0.5)-0);
        $thirdrow = ceil(($howmany * 0.75)-0);
        $thirdrow1 = ceil(($howmany * 0.75)-1);
        }

        //this makes 5 columns
        if ($columns == 5){
        $firstrow = ceil($howmany * 0.2);
        $firstrown1 = ceil(($howmany * 0.2)-1);
        $secondrow = ceil(($howmany * 0.4));
        $secondrown1 = ceil(($howmany * 0.4)-1);
        $thirdrow = ceil(($howmany * 0.6)-0);
        $thirdrow1 = ceil(($howmany * 0.6)-1);
        $fourthrow = ceil(($howmany * 0.8)-0);
        $fourthrow1 = ceil(($howmany * 0.8)-1);
        }




        foreach( $groups as $letter => $tags ) { 
            if ($columns == 2){
            if ($count == 0 || $count == $firstrow || $count ==  $secondrow) { 
                if ($count == $firstrow){
                $list .= "\n<div class='holdleft noMargin' ". $tug_width .">\n";
                $list .="\n";
                } else {
                $list .= "\n<div class='holdleft' ". $tug_width .">\n";
                $list .="\n";
                }
                }
                }
            if ($columns == 3){
            if ($count == 0 || $count == $firstrow || $count ==  $secondrow) { 
                if ($count == $secondrow){
                $list .= "\n<div class='holdleft noMargin' ". $tug_width .">\n";
                $list .="\n";
                } else {
                $list .= "\n<div class='holdleft' ". $tug_width .">\n";
                $list .="\n";
                }
                }
                }
            if ($columns == 4){             
            if ($count == 0 || $count == $firstrow || $count ==  $secondrow || $count == $thirdrow) { 
                if ($count == $thirdrow){
                $list .= "\n<div class='holdleft noMargin' ". $tug_width .">\n";
                $list .="\n";
                } else {
                $list .= "\n<div class='holdleft' ". $tug_width .">\n";
                $list .="\n";
                }
                }
                }
            if ($columns == 5){
            if ($count == 0 || $count == $firstrow || $count ==  $secondrow || $count == $thirdrow || $count == $fourthrow ) { 
                if ($count == $fourthrow){
                $list .= "\n<div class='holdleft noMargin' ". $tug_width .">\n";
                $list .="\n";
                } else {
                $list .= "\n<div class='holdleft' ". $tug_width .">\n";
                $list .="\n";
                }
                }
                }

    $list .= '<div class="tagindex">';
    $list .="\n";
    $list .='<h4>' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $letter ) . '</h4>';
    $list .="\n";
    $list .= '<ul class="links">';
    $list .="\n";           
    $i = 0;

    uasort( $tags, create_function('$a, $b', 'return strnatcasecmp($a->name, $b->name);') ); // addded 09.02.11

    foreach( $tags as $tag ) {
        /* exclude tags */
        if(isset($tag->name)){
        // added 9.28.11
        if($tag_count == "yes"){
            $mctagmap_count = ' <span class="mctagmap_count">('.$tag->count.')</span>';
        }

        $url = attribute_escape( get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ) );
        $name = apply_filters( 'the_title', $tag->name );
        if($descriptions == "yes"){
            $mctagmap_description = '<span class="tagDescription">' . $tag->description . '</span>';
        }
        //$name = ucfirst($name);
        $i++;
        $counti = $i;
        if ($hide == "yes"){
        $num2show = $num_show;
        $num2show1 = ($num_show +1);
        //$toggle = ($options['toggle']);

        if ($i != 0 and $i <= $num2show) {
            $list .= '<li><a title="' . $name . '" href="' . $url . '">' . $name . '</a>'. $mctagmap_count . $mctagmap_description . '</li>';
            $list .="\n";
            }
        if ($i > $num2show && $i == $num2show1 && $toggle == "no") {
            $list .=  "<li class=\"morelink\">"."<a href=\"#x\" class=\"more\">".$more."</a>"."</li>"."\n";
            }
        if ($i >= $num2show1){
               $list .= '<li class="hideli"><a title="' . $name . '" href="' . $url . '">' . $name . '</a>' . $mctagmap_count . $mctagmap_description . '</li>';
               $list .="\n";
        }
        } else {
            $list .= '<li><a title="' . $name . '" href="' . $url . '">' . $name . '</a>' . $mctagmap_count . $mctagmap_description . '</li>';
            $list .="\n";
        }   
        }   

    }
        if ($hide == "yes" && $toggle != "no" && $i == $counti && $i > $num2show) {
            $list .=  "<li class=\"morelink\">"."<a href=\"#x\" class=\"more\">".$more."</a>"."<a href=\"#x\" class=\"less\">".$toggle."</a>"."</li>"."\n";
        }    

    $list .= '</ul>';
    $list .="\n";
    $list .= '</div>';
    $list .="\n\n";
        if ($columns == 3 || $columns == 2){
        if ( $count == $firstrown1 || $count == $secondrown1) { 
            $list .= "</div>"; 
            }   
            }
        if ($columns == 4){
        if ( $count == $firstrown1 || $count == $secondrown1 || $count == $thirdrow1) { 
            $list .= "</div>"; 
            }   
            }
        if ($columns == 5){     
        if ( $count == $firstrown1 || $count == $secondrown1 || $count == $thirdrow1 || $count == $fourthrow1) { 
            $list .= "</div>"; 
            }   
            }

        $count++;
            } 
        } 
    $list .="</div>";
    $list .= "<div style='clear: both;'></div></div><!-- end list -->";
        }
    else $list .= '<p>Sorry, but no tags were found</p>';

return $list;

}

add_shortcode("mctagmap", "sc_mcTagMap");
// end shortcode



function mctagmap_donate($links, $file) {
$plugin = plugin_basename(__FILE__);
// create link
if ($file == $plugin) {
return array_merge( $links, array( sprintf( '<a href="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=GX8RH7F2LR74J" target="_blank">Donate to mctagmap development</a>', $plugin, __('Donate') ) ));
}
return $links;
}
add_filter( 'plugin_row_meta', 'mctagmap_donate', 10, 2 );

// the JS and CSS
add_action('wp_head', 'mcTagMapCSSandJS');
function mcTagMapCSSandJS(){
$mctagmapVersionNumber = "8.0";
$mctagmapCSSpath = './wp-content/themes/'.get_template().'/multi-column-tag-map/mctagmap.css';
    echo "\n";
    if(file_exists($mctagmapCSSpath)){
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.$mctagmapCSSpath.'?ver='.$mctagmapVersionNumber.'" type="text/css" media="screen" />';
    } else {
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/multi-column-tag-map/mctagmap.css?ver='.$mctagmapVersionNumber.'" type="text/css" media="screen" />';
    }
    echo "\n";
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="'.WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/multi-column-tag-map/mctagmap.js?ver='.$mctagmapVersionNumber.'"></script>';
    echo "\n\n";
}


// overwrite single_tag_title()
add_filter('single_tag_title', 'mctagmap_single_tag_title', 1, 2);
function mctagmap_single_tag_title($prefix = '') {
    global $wp_query;
    if ( !is_tag() )
        return;

    $tag = $wp_query->get_queried_object();

    if ( ! $tag )
        return;

    $my_tag_name = str_replace('|', '', $tag->name);
    if ( !empty($my_tag_name) ) {
        if ( $display )
            echo $prefix . $my_tag_name;
        else
            return $my_tag_name;
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

i think you are getting downvotes b/c your question is crazy vague.  if i understood from your themeshaper post then you are trying to group all your terms alphabetically like so:

A

- anvil
- apple
- art

B

- bacon
- banana

D

- darth vader
- daytime

and so on.  if this is the case, you can achieve it with get_terms() and a foreach loop

```
$terms = get_terms( 'category', array('orderby'=>'slug','order'=>'DSC'));

$xletter = NULL;

foreach($terms as $term){

   $letter = substr($term->slug, 0, 1); //gets first letter of slug

   if($letter != $xletter){  //if the letter has  changed then print it out
    echo '<h2>' .$letter . '</h2>';
}

$xletter = substr($term->slug, 0, 1); //gets first letter of slug

echo $term->name . '';  //echo the term name

}
```

Comment: Hi Helga, I was also playing around with this code. the get_terms() above only spits tag/category on the native post-type. Is there a way i can fetch tags to a certain post-type?

Comment: look at get_terms() http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

i am only getting categories, b/c that's all i had locally to test the rest on. get_terms will get whatever taxonomy you pass into it.  replace category with your tax